# Como persistir a String de um Enumerator no Banco de Dados?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, hibernate, jpa

eu tenho o seguinte Enumerator:

```
public enum ETipoCasa{

     Propria,
     Alugada,
     Financiada,
     Cedida;

}
```

E estou tentando persistir no banco a String desse enumerator conforme o exemplo:

```
Casa casa = new Casa();
casa.setTipoCasa(ETipoCasa.Alugada);
casa.inserir();
```

Estou usando o hibernate, esta gravando no banco o ordinal do enum (1), e eu queria que invés do ordinal, gravasse a String (Alugada). 
Como faço isso?

Comment: Qual a necessidade de gravar string? se um dia você trocar por Alugado vai dar conflito.. eai?

Comment: No enum não ira alterar nada, os nomes não, só a ordem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tiago**, o ideal seria realmente:

```
public enum ETipoCasa {
    Propria,
    Alugada,
    Financiada,
    Cedida;
}

public class Casa
{
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "tipo_casa")
    private ETipoCasa tipoCasa;

    public void setTipoCasa(String tipoCasa)
    {
        this.tipoCasa = tipoCasa;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Casa casa = new Casa();
    casa.setTipoCasa(ETipoCasa.Alugada);
    casa.inserir();
}
```

**Alternativa: Matar a pomba com uma bazuca**

Dar um override nos métodos do ENUM:

```
public enum ETipoCasa
{
    Propria ("Propria"),
    Alugada ("Alugada"),
    Financiada ("Financiada"),
    Cedida ("Cedida");

    private final String tipo_casa;

    private ETipoCasa(String s) {
        tipo_casa = s;
    }

    public boolean equalsName(String outroTipo)
    {
        return (outroTipo == null)? false : tipo_casa.equals(outroTipo);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return tipo_casa;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Casa casa = new Casa();
    casa.setTipoCasa(ETipoCasa.Alugada);
    casa.inserir();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tente a anotação do javax.persistence no atributo que está sendo gravado:

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)

Comment: Colega, já tentei dessa forma e não deu certo.

Comment: @TiagoFerezin, mas você recriou a tabela do banco depois de tentar a anotação?

Comment: Sim, ja recriei a tabela e nada